# Width of absolutely positioned element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have absolutely positioned div element (`.tooltip`) and another div (`.text`) inside it with text (that has `max-width` set). When `left` property of `.tooltip` is big enough it's width gets shrinked (i guess because default value of `right` property is 0). What i want, is to `.tooltip` respect the width of `.text` (it's content) in the first place. What i have tried:

1. setting width of `tooltip` to `fit-content` - this is basically what i want to achieve (showed on the snippet) but it does not work on IE (which i have to support). Without that width of `.tooltip` gets shrinked.
2. setting fixed width of `tooltip` or `text` - also not possible because text in `text` div can be pretty short and then there will be empty space.
3. on the other hand text can be really long so i can't set `white-space: nowrap` like suggested in similar questions.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  left: 400px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.text {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid green;width:500px; height: 500px; position:relative">
  <div class="tooltip">
      <div class="text">test test test test test test test test test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: a sample code or a visual illustration eg pencil scatch is much better to easily get help

Comment: here is one solution: https://jsfiddle.net/yrbsdakp/ will post it if the question get reopened

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks this kinda solves the problem that i described (and i'll accept it), however I'm already using transformations for animation purposes, do you see any other alternatives to your solution?

Comment: added an answer with another method ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On idea is to replace `left` with translation:

```css
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  left: 0;
  transform:translateX(400px);
}

.text {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid green;width:500px; height: 500px; position:relative">
  <div class="tooltip">
      <div class="text">test test test test test test test test test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to keep the use of `left`, consider some negative margin to give the element more space:

```css
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  left: 400px;
  margin-right:-400px; /* Make it bigger enough, at least the same as left */
}

.text {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid green;width:500px; height: 500px; position:relative">
  <div class="tooltip">
      <div class="text">test test test test test test test test test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```